# Using \boxed{} in \newenvironment{envname}{here}{and here}

Tags: environments, syntax, box

There's a type of environment (shown below) which I'm using very frequently. I would like to define a new environment to begin it and end it with single commands.

```
\begin{equation}\boxed{\boxed{
\begin{gathered}
    i(t)=\frac{V_s}{R}\left[1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right]\\
    \textnormal{Time Constant (} \tau_L \textnormal{)} =\frac{L}{R}
\end{gathered}
}}\end{equation}
```

However, **it seems `*\boxed{}*` cannot be split** between the beginning-and-ending braces of \newenvironment{} `\newenvironment{envname}{ *\boxed{* }{ *}* }` **(the parts enclosed in the asterisks have bad syntax).**

Splitting two instances of "`\boxed{}`" is even worse syntactically.

For reference, this is the output I want:
[image]

I have to type out these formatted equations very frequently, and **any way to condense the necessary commands is appreciated...**
**Is there a way to get around the syntactical issues** and define a \newenvironment{name}{beginning}{ending} properly? If possible, I would like to avoid using extra packages.

Sorry if any part of this post seems stupid. I'm new to StackExchange...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Should the environment include `equation` and `gathered`?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I want the environment to include both of those things

Comment: You can use if you prefer also tcolorbox package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you cannot have unbalanced braces in the begin/end code. A way out is to use `\box`es:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{boxedeq}{%
   \equation\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup$\gathered
  }{%
   \endgathered$\egroup
   \fbox{\fbox{\box0}}%
   \endequation
}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedeq}
i(t)=\frac{V_s}{R}\left[1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right] \\
\textnormal{Time Constant ($\tau_L$)} =\frac{L}{R}
\end{boxedeq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work too, thanks! What do the ```%``` signs denote though?

Comment: @Sisyphus The `%` are comment signs to hide the line endings. They are not strictly necessary *here*  but they can be crucial in other situations, or you find spurious spaces.

Comment: Ohh yeah, those. I thought perhaps they had a different purpose here. It makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: Beware that this may not be color safe.

Comment: @egrer Uhm, how so? The `$` adds a group, and `gathered` adds further three (a box, a `\ialign` and a further math group). Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 5):

With a “save box”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\doubleboxedbox}
\newenvironment{doubleboxed}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\doubleboxedbox}$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{lrbox}\boxed{\boxed{\usebox{\doubleboxedbox}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{doubleboxed}
  \begin{gathered}
    i(t)=\frac{V_s}{R}\left[1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right]\\
    \text{Time Constant ($\tau_L$)}=\frac{L}{R}
  \end{gathered}
\end{doubleboxed}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

(I simplified the input for the second line).

[image]

With `expl3` facilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{doubleboxed}{b}{\boxed{\boxed{#1}}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{doubleboxed}
  \begin{gathered}
    i(t)=\frac{V_s}{R}\left[1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right]\\
    \text{Time Constant ($\tau_L$)}=\frac{L}{R}
  \end{gathered}
\end{doubleboxed}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work, and thank you for simplifying the input!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using a patched version of the `\doublebox` command from `fancybox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{fancybox} 
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@doublebox}{\advance\fboxsep .5pt}{\advance\fboxsep 2.5pt}{}{}
\newenvironment{boxedequation}{\equation\doublebox\bgroup$\gathered}
{\endgathered$\egroup\endequation}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedequation}
    i(t)=\frac{V_s}{R}\left[1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\right]\\
    \textnormal{Time Constant (} \tau_L \textnormal{)} =\frac{L}{R}
\end{boxedequation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A bit too complicated for me right now, but it works otherwise. Might use it in the future. Thanks

Comment: I think it looks complicated because of the patch to adapt the distance between the  frames to the image posted. Try it without the patch and see what the default `\doublebox`  produces.